# Ignoring/removing specific values from an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, delete-row

I'm trying to remove unwanted information from our XML:

```
<STEP-ProductInformation ExportTime="2017-12-06 16:32:55" 
ExportContext="de_DE" ContextID="defaultcontext" WorkspaceID="Main" 
UseContextLocale="false">
<Qualifiers>
<Qualifier ID="Qualifier root">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="Qualifier root"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="AllCountries">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="AllCountries"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="std.lang.all">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="std.lang.all"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="de">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="de"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="DE">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="DE"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="fr">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="fr"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="FR">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="FR"/>
</Qualifier>
</Qualifiers>
<Products>
<Product ID="PROD1" UserTypeID="OBJ_MASTER_PRODUCT" ParentID="PARENT1">
  <Name>52470025-1</Name>
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="ATTR_1" ContextID="de_DE" 
    QualifierID="de">Je m'appelle Alex Testtest 3</Value>        
    <Value AttributeID="ATTR_2" ContextID="fr_FR" 
    QualifierID="de">Je m'appelle Alex Testtest 3</Value> 
  </Values>
</Product>  
</Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

The aim is to ignore/remove all the values relating to `ContextID="de_DE"`, making the outcome:

```
<STEP-ProductInformation ExportTime="2017-12-06 16:32:55" 
ExportContext="de_DE" ContextID="defaultcontext" WorkspaceID="Main" 
UseContextLocale="false">
<Qualifiers>
<Qualifier ID="Qualifier root">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="Qualifier root"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="AllCountries">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="AllCountries"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="std.lang.all">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="std.lang.all"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="de">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="de"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="DE">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="DE"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="fr">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="fr"/>
</Qualifier>
<Qualifier ID="FR">
  <DimensionPointLink DimensionPointID="FR"/>
</Qualifier>
</Qualifiers>
<Products>
<Product ID="PROD1" UserTypeID="OBJ_MASTER_PRODUCT" ParentID="PARENT1">
  <Name>52470025-1</Name>
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="ATTR_2" ContextID="fr_FR" 
    QualifierID="de">Je m'appelle Alex Testtest 3</Value> 
  </Values>
 </Product>  
</Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

So far I have created the following XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Value[@ContextID='de_DE']"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this excludes the Qualifier IDs and DimensionPointIDs as well as the Product ID, the UsertypeID and PartentID!

How can I achieve my objective?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the identity transformation as the starting and base point of your stylesheet as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to make sure attributes are copied as well.

Or move to Saxon 9.8 or Altova 2017/18 and XSLT 3 and simply write `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.